# How to force password set when a password is not compliant with OS restrictions?

Tags: password

I recently changed my Ubuntu login password. But now I want to change it back to the old password. But when I try that. It shows "**Not good enough**".

It was a strong password when I had set it for the first time. 
[image]

Comment: And No, It does not contain my name or username.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just alt to root and change your password like that:

```
root@hello:~# passwd Your_Name
Enter new UNIX password: 
Retype new UNIX password: 
passwd: password updated successfully
root@hello:~#
```

It doesn't care about the password history.

Or, you can chose a random password this time(like `asdkjhavbaudifsd`) and then change it back to your previous password.

Answer (score -4):

Open the Dash by clicking the Ubuntu icon in the upper-left, type "terminal", and select the Terminal application from the results that appear.

In the terminal, type

> sudo passwd

You will be prompted for your current password, enter that. Then you will be prompted for a new password and also to confirm the new password.

Comment: NO, It didn't work. i.e, it showed `passwd: password updated successfully
` but Showed password error when logging next time. Its still my current password even if it showed `passwd: password updated successfully
`

Comment: you have to do: `sudo passwd <your_user_name>` to force bypass the password check... if you do `sudo passwd` you will change the root password.

Comment: @VishwaPrakashHV Running `sudo passwd` has set the password for root, enabling login as root. You may not want this. You can run `sudo passwd -d root` to undo this.