# How to clear password history in Linux?

Tags: delete, history, passwd

How do I clean the history of previous used passwords? The history which is used by `passwd` or whatever else?

I see:

```
t-account@dbg-host: ~ $ passwd
Changing password for t-account.
Current password: 
New password: 
Retype new password: 
Password has been already used. Choose another.
```

I want to clear the list concerning "Password has been already used". How do I do this?

Thank you!

P.S. There is already the same question marked as resolved.  [How to force password set when a password is not compliant with OS restrictions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/718024/how-to-clear-password-history)
My question **is NOT** how to set/reset/repair and so on.

Comment: Old passwords are generally stored (in a hashed format) in the `/etc/security/opasswd` file. If you would like to clear them, simply blank the file.

Comment: See also pam_pwhistory on how this is setup,

Answer (score 1):

Clean user from :

```
/etc/security/opasswd
```

or clean all file:

```
/etc/security/opasswd
```

or

```
> /etc/security/opasswd
```

Comment: Details are needed. How and why would I do what you are saying here?